# No puedo hacer clic en los Item del List View

Tags: android, android-studio, listview, android-listview, click

Buenas!! Estoy tratando de que una activity muestre en un ListView datos de una BBDD, lo cual soy capaz de hacer. Pero no soy capaz de conseguir que la app me deje pulsar en los Item de ese ListView y abrir una segunda actividad con nueva información y más completa.

Adjunto el código y pantallazos!!

En la clase MisGrupos.java muestro en un ListView los grupos que contiene la BBDD:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero es pulsar en esos Item y abrir una segunda actividad (imagen de abajo) donde se muestre de otra manera estos datos y donde poder realizar otro tipo de tareas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Os dejo el codigo de ambas clases y los xml de ambos layout.

No se donde tengo el error en el código pero no me deja clicar en ninguno de los item del ListView, es como si no fuera posible hacer clic en ellos.

Muchas Gracias!!!

MisGrupos.java:

```
    package com.example.voleycoach;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.os.Bundle; 
    import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
    import android.widget.TextView;

public class MisGrupos extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView lista;
public static final String EXTRA_GRUPO_ID = "extra_grupo_id";
GruposSQLiteHelper dbGrupos;

TextView elem_Nombre, elem_Club, elem_Categoria, elem_Sexo, elem_Dias, elem_Horas;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mis_grupos);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    elem_Nombre = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.nombre_grupo);
    elem_Club = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.nombre_club);
    elem_Categoria = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.nombre_categoria);
    elem_Sexo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.nombre_sexo);
    elem_Dias = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.nombre_dias);
    elem_Horas = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.nombre_horas);

    lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewGrupos);

    dbGrupos = new GruposSQLiteHelper(this);
    Cursor cursor = dbGrupos.leerDatos();

    String[] from = new String[]{
            dbGrupos.COLUMNA_NOMBRE,
            dbGrupos.COLUMNA_CLUB, dbGrupos.COLUMNA_CATEGORIA,
            dbGrupos.COLUMNA_SEXO, dbGrupos.COLUMNA_DIAS, dbGrupos.COLUMNA_HORARIOS};

    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.nombre_grupo,
    R.id.nombre_club, R.id.nombre_categoria,
    R.id.nombre_sexo, R.id.nombre_dias, R.id.nombre_horas};

    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(MisGrupos.this,
            R.layout.elemento_lista, cursor, from, to, 0);

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    lista.setAdapter(adapter);
    lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            String aux_nombre = elem_Nombre.getText().toString();
            String aux_club = elem_Club.getText().toString();
            String aux_categoria = elem_Categoria.getText().toString();
            String aux_sexo = elem_Sexo.getText().toString();
            String aux_dias = elem_Dias.getText().toString();
            String aux_horas = elem_Horas.getText().toString();

            Intent modify_intent = new Intent(MisGrupos.this, VistaMisGrupos.class);
            modify_intent.putExtra("grupoNombre", aux_nombre);
            modify_intent.putExtra("grupoClub", aux_club);
            modify_intent.putExtra("grupoCategoria", aux_categoria);
            modify_intent.putExtra("grupoSexo", aux_sexo);
            modify_intent.putExtra("grupoDias", aux_dias);
            modify_intent.putExtra("grupoHoras", aux_horas);

            startActivity(modify_intent);
        }
    });

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(view.getContext(), Crear_Grupo.class));
        }
    });

}

}
```

VistaMisGrupos.java:

```
    package com.example.voleycoach;

 public class VistaMisGrupos extends AppCompatActivity {

private Grupo grupo;
private ImageView imageView;
final static int RESULTADO_EDITAR= 1;
final static int RESULTADO_GALERIA= 2;
final static int RESULTADO_FOTO= 3;
private Uri uriFoto;

TextView vistaGrupo, vistaClub, vistaCategoria, vistaSexo, vistaDias, vistaHoras;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_vista_mis_grupos);

    vistaGrupo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.nMisGrupo);
    vistaClub = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.nMisClub);
    vistaCategoria = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.nMisCategoria);
    vistaSexo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.nMisSexo);
    vistaDias = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.nMisHorarios);
    vistaHoras = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.nMisHoras);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = i.getExtras();

    String vistaAux_Grupo = (String) extras.get("grupoNombre");
    String vistaAux_Club = (String) extras.get("grupoClub");
    String vistaAux_Categoria = (String) extras.get("grupoCategoria");
    String vistaAux_Sexo = (String) extras.get("grupoSexo");
    String vistaAux_Dias = (String) extras.get("grupoDias");
    String vistaAux_Horas = (String) extras.get("grupoHoras");


    vistaGrupo.setText(vistaAux_Grupo);
    vistaClub.setText(vistaAux_Club);
    vistaCategoria.setText(vistaAux_Categoria);
    vistaSexo.setText(vistaAux_Sexo);
    vistaDias.setText(vistaAux_Dias);
    vistaHoras.setText(vistaAux_Horas);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.vista_grupo, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    onBackPressed();
    return true;
}
```

}

activity_mis_grupos.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.voleycoach.MisGrupos">

   <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewGrupos"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
    android:dividerHeight="2dp"></ListView>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

activity_vista_mis_grupos.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.voleycoach.VistaMisGrupos">

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="495dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageGrupo"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_report_image" 
        />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:contentDescription="logo galeria"
                    android:onClick="galeria"
                    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:contentDescription="logo galeria"
                    android:onClick="galeria"
                    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:contentDescription="Eliminar foto"
                    android:onClick="eliminarFoto"

     android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/t_MisGrupo"
                    android:layout_width="185dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Nombre del Grupo:"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/nMisGrupo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Grupo"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/t_MisClub"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Club: "
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/nMisClub"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Club"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/t_MisCategoria"
                    android:layout_width="105dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Categoría: "
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/nMisCategoria"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Categoria"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/t_MisSexo"
                    android:layout_width="108dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Sexo:"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/nMisSexo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Sexo"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/n_MisEntrenos"
                    android:layout_width="144dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Entrenamientos:"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/nMisHorarios"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Dias"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/nMisHoras"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Horas"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btAsistencia"
                    style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Inset"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Asistencia" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btJugadoras"
                    style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Inset"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Jugadoras" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btFisico"
                    style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Inset"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.90"
                    android:text="Datos Físicos" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btCalendario"
                    style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Inset"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Calendario" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_vista_mis_grupos"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Intenta ser mas específico sobre el error. Se te detiene la aplicación? Que dice el log cat?

Comment: Perdón, no lo especifiqué...La App no se detiene simplemente no puedo pulsar sobre los Item de la lista, es como si no estuvieran habilitados o algo asi...en el Log Cat no me aparece nada en concreto

Comment: @AMC tratá de revisar si al dar click se muestra algo en el LogCat.

Comment: @AMC pusiste el código en depuración para probar si realmente no entraba al onItemClick ?, porque creo que el problema seria realmente, que si la actividad no inicia, es porque estas utilizando el contexto de la subclase y no del activity. En ese caso deberias utilizar: MisGrupos.this.startActivity... en vez de utilizar startActivity dentro de la subclase. Dejame saber si ese es el error para hacer una respuesta formal. Eso sucede porque la Actividad que vas a iniciar no esta relacionada con la que tienes activa actualmente.